# XSD + regex. Incorrect rule?

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I wrote XML type in my XSD file:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="refId">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
      <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
      <xs:minLength value="5"/>
      <xs:pattern value="^ref-"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

All values must start with "ref-" text. But I get incorrect result for string: "ref-title". Why does this happen?

Comment: What's your regex expression? Is it related to regex?

Comment: >What's your regex expression? Is it related to regex?
Yes it is regex. I didn't understand, why it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern applies to the whole string rather than just finding a match inside the string, you'll probably find that

```
<xs:pattern value="ref-.*" />
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

The circumflex ^ does not represent "start of string" in the XSD regex dialect, it represents itself. Therefore your pattern says that the ID values must start with "^", which of course would make them invalid IDs. XSD patterns are implicitly anchored, so value="ref-.*" is what you need.